# Python and nGrams

Tags: python, syntax, nltk, aster

Aster user here that is trying to move completely over to python for basic text analytics.
I am trying to replicate the output of ASTER ngram in Python using nltk or some other module. I need to be able to do this for ngrams of 1 thru 4. Output to csv.

**DATA:**

```
Unique_ID, Text_Narrative
```

**OUTPUT NEEDED:**

```
Unique_id, ngram(token), ngram(frequency)
```

**Example output:**

- 023345  "I"  1
- 023345  "Love"  1
- 023345  "Python"  1

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, can you include some code of what you attempted? What is the main issue?

Comment: We aren't a coding service.  Please show us what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: you need couple of things - `open` or `csv.writer` for the file writing, then I would recommend `Counter` from `collections` and that's pretty much it. Do you want the frequency within the unique_ID string or altogether?

Comment: apologies- as I am new to Python and open source in general. In my research, I've discovered several different 'ways' to do ngrams in Python. So my question is which method would you recommend to mimmick the ASTER output (if you're familiar with ASTER)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this simple version only with `python`'s standard library,  for educational reasons.

Production code should use `spacy` and `pandas`

```
import collections
from operator import itemgetter as at
with open("input.csv",'r') as f:
    data = [l.split(',', 2) for l in f.readlines()]
spaced = lambda t: (t[0][0],' '.join(map(at(1), t))) if t[0][0]==t[1][0] else []
unigrams = [(i,w) for i, d in data for w in d.split()]
bigrams = filter(any, map(spaced, zip(unigrams, unigrams[1:] )))
trigrams = filter(any, map(spaced, zip(unigrams, unigrams[1:], unigrams[2:])))
with open("output.csv", 'w') as f:
    for ngram in [unigrams, bigrams, trigrams]:
        counts = collections.Counter(ngram)
        for t,count in counts.items():
            f.write("{i},{w},{c}\n".format(c=count, i=t[0], w=t[1]))
```

Comment: thanks Uri- this code has gotten me halfway there. Can you share the adjustment that would me to run an ngram of 2 words, 3 words, etc etc ?

Comment: I've added bigrams and trigrams calculation, Please accept the answer if it was helpful. If you have any additional requests, please ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

As the others said the question is really vague but since you are new here's a long form guide. :-)

```
from collections import Counter

#Your starting input  - a phrase with an ID
#I added some extra words to show count
dict1 = {'023345': 'I love Python love Python Python'}


#Split the dict vlue into a list for counting
dict1['023345'] = dict1['023345'].split()

#Use counter to count
countlist = Counter(dict1['023345'])

#count list is now "Counter({'I': 1, 'Python': 1, 'love': 1})"

#If you want to output it like you requested, interate over the dict
for key, value in dict1.iteritems(): 
    id1 = key
    for key, value in countlist.iteritems():
        print id1, key, value
```